# Does Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities 4.0 support the hierarchyid datatype

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities, .net-4.0

Is their a way to use linq to SQL/Entities 4.0 to work with the hierarchy datatype?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None of the Microsoft family of ORMs can currently use CLR User-Defined Types (which includes the built-in `hierarchyid` and geospatial types) as column types.

If you use these in your database, you have two workarounds:

1. Add a computed column to the hierarchy table with the expression `CAST(hid AS varbinary892))`.  You'll need to make sure that you include this column in **every** query (including stored procedures) that gets used by Linq.  Then, add *this* column to the entity mapping.

   At this point, you can extend the entity's partial class to add the "real" `hierarchyid` column as its own property by adding a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServerTypes` and using the `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` classes to convert the BLOB data to/from `SqlHierarchyId`.

   Note that **you can't write Linq queries against this column**.  You'll just get a "no supported translation" error if you try.  So keep in mind that this is a **limited** workaround.
2. The other option, and the one I generally prefer, is to not use the `hierarchyid` column at all from within L2S/EF.  Add a separately-indexed surrogate auto-inc key to the hierarchy table and treat the `hierarchyid` as an implementation detail.  Use UDFs and Views to implement hierarchical queries that only require the surrogate ID as a parameter.

   This sounds like a pain, but it's not really that bad if you work this way from the get-go.  Before Microsoft introduced the `hierarchyid` type, I was using an adaptation of Dennis Forbes' materialized path hierarchy, which was based around an adjacency list and maintaining the path as a kind of denormalization.  `hierarchyid` makes this a lot easier to do.

   Unfortunately I don't have a complete working example of everything you need to do to maintain the correct associations between a `hierarchyid` and adjacency list, but if you read [Dennis's article](http://www.yafla.com/papers/sqlhierarchies/sqlhierarchies2.htm) it should be a good start.  Don't implement the materialized path, use `hierarchyid` instead, but read the sections about implementing self-maintaining hierarchies with triggers.

   If Microsoft ever does implement support for `hierarchyid` in their ORMs, it would be easy to remove the adjacency list and switch exclusively to a solution based on `hierarchyid`.  But since managing hierarchies based around `hierarchyid` require a slew of stored procedures to maintain *anyway* (since you don't get "automatic" IDs), you should get comfortable with writing a lot of SQL UDFs and Stored Procedure abstractions around hierarchical queries.

Comment: Whoa..Thanks alot. I just decided to convert the hierarchyid to a blob and converting it back to a hierarchyid. I am researching how to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. Not directly, anyway. You might be able to [work around it similarly to geospatial types](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/yes-you-can-read-and-probably-write-spatial-data-with-entity-framework/), though. I haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

We use a similar solution to Aaronaught's with Linq to SQL.

We have create computed columns

```
    TreeId.ToString()
```

for the current hierarchyid-column and

```
    [TreeId].[GetAncestor](1).ToString()
```

for the direct parent's.

We also created a view that excludes the hierarchyid-column and dragged this view onto the Dbml-diagram and set up associations to referenced tables.

Most hierarchyid-functionality needs to be in the form of stored procedures though.